# Change the color in bpy

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

I want to give the color to the human body mesh that was loaded from the .obj file as v,vn, vt,f I want to give the color with a specific formula as color=(n*e+1)/2)*225 where n is vn, normal vector, and e is sun position can be from above as (0,0,1) and the color should fill the triangle of the given normal vector.[image]

Here is my sample code but it is not working

```
import bpy
import math
# Set up the scene
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
# Import the human body model
bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath="C:\\Users\\Desktop\\body_script\\body_triangular.obj")
# Rename the imported object
human_obj = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
human_obj.name = "Human"
# Add a Sun lamp to the scene
bpy.ops.object.light_add(type='SUN', location=(0,0,0))
sun = bpy.data.objects['Sun']
sun.name = "Sun"
sun.data.direction = (0, 0, 1)
# Get the sun position
e = math.cos(sun.rotation_euler[0])
# Define the color function
def get_color(n, e):
    r = (n[0]*e+1)/2 * 255
    g = (n[1]*e+1)/2 * 255
    b = (n[2]*e+1)/2 * 255
    return (r, g, b)
# Loop through the vertices and set their colors
human_mesh = human_obj.data
for poly in human_mesh.polygons:
    for loop_index in range(poly.loop_start, poly.loop_start + poly.loop_total):
        n = human_mesh.loops[loop_index].normal
        color = get_color(n, e)
        if len(human_mesh.vertex_colors) == 0:
            human_mesh.vertex_colors.new()
        human_mesh.vertex_colors.active.data[loop_index].color = color
```

Comment: Could you explain what you want to obtain and what is not working?

Comment: it displays the body but it is not putting the colors

Comment: I want to color each triangular section in the picture as color = ((normal.dot(sun_pos) + 1) / 2) * 255 here, normal - vn normal vector of the triangle, I want to fill it as each triangle color  = (color, color, color, 255)

Comment: ok, afaik, sun data has no "direction". What do you mean by this line?

Comment: Okay, okay how to fill each triangle randomly then ?

Comment: what do you mean by "randomly"?

Comment: Hello, Szabi .. welcome.. To avoid this question  being clobbered for being [XY](https://xyproblem.info/), I think it would be much better to illustrate / indicate the desired _end effect_ of this code.

Comment: The task is I need to color each triangular with the formula of (vn*e+1)/2 * 255, vn is the normal vector of the face, and e is the sun position can be (0,0,1).

Answer (score 0):

ok, all is not clear about what is the goal here (in my opinion).

But here are some modifications for the end of your script (with needed comments added).

Also you'll need to remove

```
sun.data.direction = (0, 0, 1)
```

because sun has no `direction`in its data.

```
def get_color(n, e):
    # blender's colors are from 0 to 1
    # so I removed "* 255"
    r = (n[0]*e+1)/2
    g = (n[1]*e+1)/2
    b = (n[2]*e+1)/2
    return (r, g, b, 1) # added "1", because vcol are rgba

# Loop through the vertices and set their colors
human_mesh = human_obj.data

# This can be done once (so outside of the loop)
if len(human_mesh.vertex_colors) == 0:
    human_mesh.vertex_colors.new()
for poly in human_mesh.polygons:
    n = poly.normal
    # as you need to use the face normal, the calculation below
    # can be done once per face
    color = get_color(n, e)
    for loop_index in range(poly.loop_start, poly.loop_start + poly.loop_total):
        #n = human_mesh.loops[loop_index].normal << this is not the face normal
        human_mesh.vertex_colors.active.data[loop_index].color = color
```

Using Suzanne, that gives the following result:

[image]