# Blender face colorize

Tags: python

How can I use the bpy module in Blender to load a human body mesh from a .obj file and colorize each face of the mesh based on the angle between the face's normal vector and the direction of the sun?

Specifically, I want to color each face of the mesh using the following formula: (vn•e + 1) / 2, where vn is the normal vector of the face, e is the direction of the sun, and • represents the dot product between vn and e.

Comment: Have you read the answer about your nearly exact same question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/291303/19156 ?

Comment: yes but it is not working

Comment: it does work... if something goes wrong for you, comment below the answer